# How to structure the presentation of a square overlay like the Music app on iPad?

Tags: ipad, uiviewcontroller, childviewcontroller

I need to create an interface that's basically the same as how the iPad Music app displays track lists in the albums tab - a square in the center of the view containing a view controller's view, with the playback controls still accessible at the top. Tapping the gray area around the view should dismiss it.

How would I go about doing that while still supporting iOS 5? Is it just a case of creating a view controller and adding it's view as a subview? Or is there something I should do with view controller containment?

I've attached a screenshot to show what I mean (smudged to hide the brand etc). The white square in the Center needs to be able to contain a variety of view controllers, often managed by a navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: The view controller containment APIs were introduced in iOS 5, so it shouldn't be a problem to make it compatible with that. You might want to watch session 102 in the WWDC 2011 videos, it addresses pretty much exactly this use case.

Comment: Thanks omz, I'll make that my bedtime viewing tonight :)

Comment: OK I got it working quite nicely. I'll write an answer soon so others can learn too.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, Music just presents a modal view controller using [`UIModalPresentationFormSheet`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH111-SW15). You can do this either programmatically or in a storyboard segue -- see the "presentation" popup in the inspector when you select the segue.

Comment: Unlikely. That wouldn't allow you to interact with the background.

Comment: Yeah, what omz said plus the fact that the player controls at the top would be grayed out.